# Why can't I convert PDFs to JPGs using RMagick in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, imagemagick, rmagick

I am trying to create a thumbnail from a pdf in Rails:

```
def create_thumbnail
  # pdf = Magick::ImageList.new("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/test.pdf") # works
  pdf = Magick::ImageList.new(invoice_path(invoice, :locale => "en", :format => "pdf")) # does not work
  pdf.write("#{invoice.number}_thumbnail.jpg")
end
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
unable to open image `/en/invoices/196.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2584`
```

This is my controller:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    disposition = params[:disposition] || "inline"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do |pdf|
        pdf = InvoicePdf.new(@invoice, view_context)
        send_data(pdf.render, :filename => invoice_filename(@invoice), :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "inline")
      end
    end   
  end
```

What am I missing here?

Is there no way to generate jpegs from inline pdfs in Rails?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The problem is that you provide a relative URL, which is interpreted as an absolute UNIX file identifier. You could try to change invoice_path to invoice_url, so you'll get an absolute URL, but I do not know whether ImageList can download from remote sources. Otherwise you'd have to download it manually, store in temp location and pass that path to ImageList.

Comment: @lawitschka: That's what I thought. Using absolute paths doesn't make a difference, though. Still getting the same error that way.

Comment: Are your pdf's being cached at all, or are they being generated every single time you visit '/en/invoices/196.pdf'? If so, how long does it take to generate the pdf? Maybe RMagick is timing out when it tries to hit the url? I think @lawitschka isn't asking for an absolute PATH, but instead an absolute URL, so that RMagick understands that it is accessing a website and might need to wait a bit longer to get a response.

Comment: you could iuse `Image.read_inline` to get image from Base64-encoded string.